# PyTorch LogSoftmax vs Softmax for CrossEntropyLoss

Tags: pytorch, cross-entropy

I understand that PyTorch's LogSoftmax function is basically just a more numerically stable way to compute `Log(Softmax(x))`. Softmax lets you convert the output from a Linear layer into a categorical probability distribution.

The [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) says that CrossEntropyLoss combines `nn.LogSoftmax()` and `nn.NLLLoss()` in one single class.

Looking at `NLLLoss`, I'm still confused...Are there 2 logs being used? I think of negative log as information content of an event. (As in [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)))

After a bit more looking, I think that `NLLLoss` assumes that you're actually passing in log probabilities instead of just probabilities. Is this correct? It's kind of weird if so...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, `NLLLoss` takes log-probabilities (`log(softmax(x))`) as input. Why?. Because if you add a `nn.LogSoftmax` (or `F.log_softmax`) as the final layer of your model's output, you can easily get the probabilities using `torch.exp(output)`, and in order to get cross-entropy loss, you can directly use `nn.NLLLoss`. Of course, log-softmax is more stable as you said.

And, there is only one log (it's in `nn.LogSoftmax`). There is no log in `nn.NLLLoss`.

`nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` combines `nn.LogSoftmax()` (that is, `log(softmax(x))`) and `nn.NLLLoss()` in one single class. Therefore, the output from the network that is passed into `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` needs to be the raw output of the network (called logits), not the output of the softmax function.

Comment: Given that the network gives raw output to the Cross Entropy Loss during training, do I need to add a LogSoftMax layer during inference?

Comment: Not necessarily, if you want to get the probability, then only you'd want to use Softmax, provided your model gives logits.

Comment: The NLLoss() not having a log is a PyTorch quirk. The definition of negative log likelihood has a log in it: https://notesbylex.com/negative-log-likelihood.html. The OP is right to be confused.